# How to use a dedicated template for the Custom Post Type from a plugin?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, page-template

I'm working through [this tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-creation-display-and-meta-boxes/) on Custom Post Types (in a plugin) wherein the author demonstrates how to **force the use of a dedicated template for the Custom Post Type**. The author states thus:

> The code (below) searches for the template `single-movie-reviews.php` in the current theme directory. If it is not found then it looks into the plugin directory for the template, which we supply as a part of the plugin. The template_include hook was used to change the default behavior and enforce a specific template.

**Step 1: Added this code to my `plugin-name.php` file**

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_reviews_template', 1 );
function include_reviews_template(){
    if ( get_post_type() == 'reviews' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array( 'single-movie-reviews.php' ) ) ) {
                    $template_path = $theme_file;
                } else {
                    $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/single-movie-reviews.php';
            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;
}
```

**Step 2: Create the single-{custom-post-type}.php file.**

Next, I created the requisite `single-movie-reviews.php` file and added it to `'/my-plugin/templates/'` directory.

The author adds the following:

> **Note:** You need to create a new page **from the dashboard** using the newly
>   created template.

**The Problems**

1. The Page template does NOT show in the dashboard
2. When I visited the post I created using the Custom Post Type, it **does show** the post using the page template from the plugin. ***However***... every other page *(i.e. pages **NOT** using the CPT)* now show **a blank white screen** (as though it cannot find the proper template to use).

So what am I doing wrong?

Please advise

Comment: Note, in your example of:

`$template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/single-movie-reviews.php';`

that `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` already includes the trailing slash. So, as far as I know, the `/` before templates isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
function include_reviews_template(){
```

To this:

```
function include_reviews_template( $template_path ) {
```

When `get_post_type() == 'reviews'` is false you are returning an unset variable (`$template_path`). This change should send the value passed to the function by WordPress.

Comment: Dang! Missed that. Good catch!

Comment: I also notice that problem #1 still exists: The Template Page is not showing in the list of templates. Given the code above, should that show?

Comment: If you are you referring to the drop down list of page templates in the WordPress Page Editor, that list is updated by searching each template file for a line near the top with the text "Template Name:" in it.

Comment: I guess it does not search the plugins directory(?), as I have a file setup as a template file in there. It's not seeing it.

Comment: I don't know if there is a hook to have WP search other directories.

Comment: I see that is an "issue". See this post by Tom McFarlin on "Including a WordPress Page Template in a Plugin". http://bit.ly/18eyT8j